# Extact frequencies from logical lists for every row

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,1), matrix = c("c(\"TRUE\", \"TRUE\")", "c(\"FALSE\", \"TRUE\", \"FALSE\")"))
```

> ```
> id                      matrix
> 1  1           c("TRUE", "TRUE")
> 2  1 c("FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE")
> ```

How is it possible to count for every row the frequencies of true, false and the total?

Example of expected output

```
id true_num false_num frq_list
1     2        0         2
1     1        2         3
```

Comment: How did you create that data.frame? It's very odd that your "matrix" column is formatted as a factor/character value. Those values will have to be re-parsed so you can operate with them. It would be easier to work with if those didn't turn into character values so maybe it's worth going back a step to try to fix that problem first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it using regular expressions since your 'logical' vector is already just a string:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(id = c(1,1), matrix = c("c(\"TRUE\", \"TRUE\")", "c(\"FALSE\", \"TRUE\", \"FALSE\")")) %>% 
  transmute(id = id,
            true_num = str_count(matrix, pattern = 'T'),
            false_num = str_count(matrix, pattern = 'F'),
            frq_list = true_num + false_num)
#>   id true_num false_num frq_list
#> 1  1        2         0        2
#> 2  1        1         2        3
```

Wether this is really a *good* idea is another question.

Comment: thank you. I receive this error `Error: Column `id` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable
`

Comment: That error means, that you used a `group_by` in your pipeline before. You need to add `ungroup` before doing the `transmute`-ing